# Android Studio Radio button save state in listview fetched from sqlite

Tags: java, android, listview

So i have an application where i fetched some poll from an sqlite db and used them in listview and now i tried to add a radio button but when i hit a button back that i created it doesn't save the choice i did from the radio button.

i open the app and...

[i choose the second thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtLEL.jpg)

[but when i go back and in again the first is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhlR8.jpg)

here is my listAdapter.java

```
package com.hfad.myapp.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.hfad.myapp.R;
import com.hfad.myapp.model.Cases;

import java.util.List;

public class ListCases extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Cases> mCasesList;

public ListCases(Context mContext, List<Cases> mCasesList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mCasesList = mCasesList;
}
    int pose = 0;
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCasesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mCasesList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mCasesList.get(position).getID();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_listview, null);
    TextView tvName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_case_name);
    TextView tvSize = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_case_size);
    TextView tvMsize = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_case_msize);
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    radioButton.setChecked(position == pose);
    radioButton.setTag(position);
    radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pose = (Integer)view.getTag();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    tvName.setText(mCasesList.get(position).getBrand());
    tvSize.setText(mCasesList.get(position).getSize());
    tvMsize.setText(mCasesList.get(position).getMsize());
    return v;
}
}
```

i remind you that i did a database connection with an external database
it's really frustrating i couldn't find something similar and i can't solve this please help.
p.s. for any mistakes...i am really new in java and android studio in general.

Comment: The adapter is simply displaying the data it is given.  You need to write the data back to the DB at some point. Try in `onPause()` - [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle)

Comment: i just want them to be displayed i won't insert anything back in. what do you mean with onPause()? by the way i i just need to save the radio button state as long i'm in the app i don't care what happens when i close and re-open the app

Comment: The android doc states something along the lines that a given page will be destroyed while it is not active.  (Even changing screen orientation will cause an activity/fragment to be destroyed/re-created.)  If your requirements are basic you can maintain states of specific items. [Lifecycle & States](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState).  Essentially maintaining a selected index for your listview.  there are plenty of examples to be found on this site for statefulness.